# Spring MVC - Send email, Bean creation

Tags: email, spring-mvc

I'm trying to set up my Spring MVC app to send email, but i think i'm doing something wrong in the configuration

In My AppConfig i instantiate the Bean:

```
@Bean
    public JavaMailSender mailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");


        return mailSender;
    }
```

Then in my application.properties I have:

```
mail.port= 465
mail.host= smtp.gmail.com
mail.username= username
mail.password= password
emailTo = info@beingsmart.it
emailSubject = ALERT - ePark Server 

mail.smtp.auth = true
mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true

mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback = false
```

When I try to send the email i'm getting

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender]: Factory method 'mailSender' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/AuthenticationFailedException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/AuthenticationFailedException
    at it.besmart.config.AppConfig.mailSender(AppConfig.java:128)
    at it.besmart.config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b2a09c0.CGLIB$mailSender$7(<generated>)
    at it.besmart.config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b2a09c0$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$dd65f050.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:318)
    at it.besmart.config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b2a09c0.mailSender(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    ... 61 more
```

EDIT
I added javax mail to my pom

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

Now I have a different exception when trying to send the email

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/MessageRemovedIOException
```

It looks like an authentication error, but i'm thinking that JavaMailSender does not takes the setting in my application.properties, could it be?

Thanks

Comment: It is missingdependency, not authentication error

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be missing dependency rather than anything else. If using spring boot have dependency like:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If you don't I suggest you look inside that POM and figure out what are the missing pieces.

In your particular case it seems you need:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Generic advice:

1. `ClassNotFoundException` means class which you need is not on classpath. It's *usually* a missing dependency
2. Google to find which jar contains the missing class
3. Find the library it on maven central
4. Add to dependencies

Comment: I'm not using spring boot but spring mvc

Comment: Here is what they pull: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-mail/pom.xml. I think you miss the javax.mail dependency

Comment: Clarified the answer with the exact dependency you need